# Gif de carregamento antes dos dados chegarem na página

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

estou trazendo os dados do servidor através de um NGFOR com o pipe async mas gostaria de mostrar um gif de carregamento até os dados chegarem, demora uns 3 segundos para os dados aparecerem na tela e gostaria de mostrar um gif de loading...

```
    <table cellpadding="5">
    <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let contato of contatos | async">
      <td><img src="../../assets/{{contato.key}}.png" alt="facebook"></td>
      <td class="redes">{{contato.data}}</td>
    </tr>      
  </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Mas não é só colocar um **`if`** nas duas **td**?!

Comment: eu tentei fazer isso e não consegui, tem como me ajudar com o código ?

Comment: Coloca aí a maneira que tentou

Comment: tentei fazer um NgIF na variavel do for se ela fosse diferente de nulo mostraria as TD mas não deu certo

Comment: Edite a resposta e coloque no código da pergunta aí amigo pra ver como vc fez!

Comment: O jeito que eu fiz não deu certo amigo... pra quê vou postar ?

Comment: Ué, pq é mais fácil ver o que já tentou, e tentar corrigir do que ficar especulando como fez.

Comment: https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/angular-ngif-async-pipe

Answer (score 0):

Isso deve resolver seu caso:

```
 <table cellpadding="5">
    <tbody>
    <tr *ngIf="!contatos || (contatos && contatos.length == 0)">
       <!- gif aqui -->
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let contato of contatos | async">
      <td><img src="../../assets/{{contato.key}}.png" alt="facebook"></td>
      <td class="redes">{{contato.data}}</td>
    </tr>      
  </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: funcionou não, mas vlw ai a tentativa amigo....